# Remove onClick Attribute from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, overriding, android-databinding

I have an image view with an onClick attribute in xml as shown below:

```
android:onClick="@{(view)->globalBinding.onItemClicked(view,trackingViewModel.getSearchStyle())}"
```

I also have an onClick defined programatically. At some special conditions I want the onClick defined in the fragment to work, so I want to remove the onClick in xml.

In other words at times, I want to override the onclick in xml with click listener in fragment. How can I do that?

Comment: get the id of ImageView inside your fragment view and implement setOnClickListener()

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes I did that but since there is an onClick in the xml, the click listener in the fragment is not working

Comment: Remove the onClick from the XML

Comment: then remove it. you are getting your work done with above method.

Comment: @DKIT i can't remove the onClick, i need it to work normally and in some cases i need to override it.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes Cant remove the onClick in xml

Comment: You should not override the event then, you should override the method the onClick event is calling.

Comment: @DKIT How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put some conditions in your xml file, here i am giving you a sample with use of boolean variable in xml

```
android:onClick="@{(view)-> variable ? globalBinding.onItemClicked(view,trackingViewModel.getSearchStyle()) : viewModel.onOtherClick(view)}"
```

Here `variable` is a boolean variable, you can take reference of your own variable.

`viewModel.onOtherClick` is a method available in `ViewModel`, you can take reference of your own method from `ViewModel` or `Interface`

If you want to remove clicklistener in some conditions, just put `null` in place of `viewModel.onOtherClick`

Comment: how will i control which method is getting called? I mean how can i change the value of `variable`..

Comment: you need to take variable inside `<variable>` tag in your xml, and from java you can access it as `binding.setVariable()`, Ex. If your variable name is `active`, you can access it as `binding.setActive()`

Comment: can i use it to call a method in the fragment?

Comment: Yes, why not, take a look at basic `data-binding` examples and you will get everything

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the click listener, even if it's an xml attribute:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

You can't get the listener after it's set, unless you use reflection and that's very performance-degrading and bad code style.

The way I would personally do it is to not use XML properties for this case.  Instead, create an enum for the 2 states your image is going to be in:

```
public enum StateHolder {
    FIRST_STATE,
    SECOND_STATE;

    OnClickListener getListener(StateHolder state) {
        switch (state) {
            case FIRST_STATE: return view -> //return listener for whatever happens by default here; 
            case SECOND_STATE: return view -> // whatever happens in the second state here;
            default: throw new IllegalStateException(); // do whatever here
        }
    }

    void swapListeners(View view) {
        StateHolder current = (StateHolder) view.getTag();
        view.setOnClickListener(getListener(current));
        view.setTag(current == FIRST_STATE ? SECOND_STATE : FIRST_STATE);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to set the tag when you first create your view to avoid a NullPointerException! Also, depending on whether or not it's a stateful operation then you might want to make the listeners final instance objects to avoid re-creating instances needlessly.

Comment: i tried `imageView.setOnClickListener(null);` The click listener in the xml was still consuming the click. 
is what i am asking impossible?(using both click listeners simultaneously?)

Comment: @free_style granted, I haven't used or seen the binding syntax that you use, so I don't exactly know about your specific case. Regardless, though, no I don't think there's any other way to do it that to programatically create *both* instances.  This is because there doesn't seem to be a way to recover your first instance of the listener and re-use it (other than reflection). The enum will make it pretty painless though, or make one listener and check a condition.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `onClick` from the xml and set a `ClickListener` for the View in your `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` if it's a `Fragment`.

e.g.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.theViewId); // cast it if necessary
v.setOnClickListener(); // set it here with the code
```

Comment: I cant remove the onClick from the xml. is there any way to override the onClick?

Comment: @free_style Did you try it? Normally `setOnClickListener` should override it.

Comment: @free_style If you can not modify the xml then I don't see any other way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewId);
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...your on click code here...
        }
    });
```

Comment: since there is an onClick in the xml this is not working.